# Reference - Schwarz's Proof of Clairaut's Theorem

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, real-analysis

Where can I find a copy (online) of Schwarz's paper that proved Clairaut's theorem for mixed partial derivatives?

His paper is: Schwarz, H. A., "Communication", Archives des Sciences Physiques et Naturelles, (1873), v. 48, pp. 38-45.

Comment: My two 4 March 2021 comments to [this *Mathematics Educators* answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/19569/745) will likely be of interest to anyone interested in Schwarz's result.

Answer (score 4):

You can download  the journal here:

https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/bibliography/5919#/summary

There are also Collected works of Schwarz:

https://archive.org/details/gesammeltemathem02schwuoft